# Tensorflow Wide&Deep tutorial Example with batch

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am excited about the new model (i.e., wide_n_deep learning) released by Google and Tensorflow. So I am trying to play with it by running [the tutorial example](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/wide_and_deep/index.html).

As a common trick in Machine Learning, batch learning is important when the entire training data set is big. So I try to modify the provided wide_n_deep learning tutorial example to get batch learning, as follows:

```
index_in_epoch = 0
num_examples = df_train.shape[0]
for i in xrange(FLAGS.train_steps):
    startTime = datetime.now()
    print("start step %i" %i)
    start = index_in_epoch
    index_in_epoch += batch_size
    if index_in_epoch > num_examples:
        if start < num_examples:
          m.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_train[start:num_examples], steps=1)
        df_train.reindex(np.random.permutation(df_train.index)
        start = 0
        index_in_epoch = batch_size
    if i%5 == 1:
        results = m.evaluate(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_test), steps = 1)
        for key in sorted(results):
          print("%s: %s %(key, results[key]))
    end = index_in_epoch
    m.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_train[start:end], steps=1)
```

Simply speaking, I iterate the entire training data set batch by batch, and for every batch, I call the "fit" function to re-train the model.

The problem of this naive strategy is that the processing time is too much slow (for instance, we want to iterate a 4-million-record data set 100 times, with batch size to be 100k, the training and evaluation time would be approximately 1 week). So I really doubt I am using the batch learning in a proper way.

I would be appreciate if any talent can share your experience to handle the batch learning when playing with the wide_n_deep learning model.

Comment: Those training times are not uncommon. Imagenet takes about 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Every fit/evaluate call creates a graph and a session, then does the operation. If you do that in the loop, it will be slow. 
To make it faster, you need to provide an `input_fn` which will be called tensors batch by batch.
If you read data from a dataframe you can use `to_feature_columns_and_input_fn`
If you read data from a file which holds `tf.Example`, you can use something like `read_batch_examples` in your `input_fn`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As a beginner to tensorflow, I can understand the reason why my approach to handle batches is slow, after reading your comments. It would be more helpful if you can provide a more concrete example on how to read batch by batch according to your suggestion. Thanks for your help.